# R add new column with predefined pattern

Tags: r, matrix

I'm trying to learn [how to provide a reproducible R example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) in case I needed one in the future.

I use the `SimSurv()` function and I want to add six new columns (binary variables) to it. These columns' values should not be parallel or intersecting ie. `var1` must have the value 1 for elements 1 to 100 and the rest 0; `var2` will start at 101 to 200 and so on.

```
x = SimSurv(600)
var1 = matrix(0:1, nrow=100) # 1 - 100
var2 = matrix(0:1, nrow=100) # 101 - 200
...
var6 = matrix(0:1, nrow=100) # 501 - 600
```

I can not phrase this one into a legitimate Google search thus I asked here to expound my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with `gl()`  and `model.matrix()`:

```
y <- gl(6, 100)
mat <- model.matrix(~y-1) # -1 is for remove the intercept
colnames(mat) <- paste0('var', 1:6)
mat
```

Comment: +1 cool - I never really use this function. I should remember this one more! Nice answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you can do this with `rep` and `matrix` like so:

```
m <- rep( rep( c( 1 , 0 ) , times = c( 100 , 600 ) ) , 6 )
matrix( m[1:3600] , nrow = 600 , byrow = FALSE )
```

On an example 100 times smaller this gives the following, non-intersecting binary variable columns:

```
m <- rep( rep( c( 1 , 0 ) , times = c( 1 , 6 ) ) , 6 )
matrix( m[1:36] , nrow = 6 , byrow = FALSE )
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#[1,]    1    0    0    0    0    0
#[2,]    0    1    0    0    0    0
#[3,]    0    0    1    0    0    0
#[4,]    0    0    0    1    0    0
#[5,]    0    0    0    0    1    0
#[6,]    0    0    0    0    0    1
```